# const array of string - при выводе кракозябры вместо русских символов

Tags: delphi, массивы, кодировка, строки

Задаю массив констант:

```
TfrmEmployersEditInsert = class(TForm)
private
    const Captions: array[0..8] of String = ('Ф.И.О.','Профессия','Таб. №', '№ бр.', 'Телефон','Рост', 'Одежда', 'Обувь', 'Пол');
```

В цикле вывожу элемент массива:

```
if Trim(aEdit.Text) = '' then begin
    aStr := 'Заполните поле '+aCaptions[i]+'!';
    MessageDlg(aStr,mtWarning,mbOKCancel,0);
    aEdit.SetFocus;
    exit;
end;
```

Выводит кракозябры. Если задаю просто константу const Captions = 'Ф.И.О.', то символы при выводе отображаются корректно.
Также при создании класса и инициализации объекта в теле процедуры:

```
Type
  TCaptions = array of string;

...

var
  aCaptions: TCaptions;
begin
  aCaptions := TCaptions.Create('Ф.И.О.','Профессия','Таб. №', '№ бр.', 'Телефон',
          'Рост', 'Одежда', 'Обувь', 'Пол');
end;
```

выводятся корректные русские символы.
Почему при использовании массива констант русские символы отображаются некорректно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Версия Delphi наверное выше 2009?
Вместо **String** используйте **AnsiString**

Comment: Помогло. Версия 2007.